# Unreal Engine 4 - Export variable

Tags: variables, export, unreal-engine4

I'm new to unreal engine 4 and have a relatively simple question. How can i export a value from a variable to a .txt file?

I tried "WriteToFile" but can't get it to work. Any help is appreciated.

Answer (score 0):

I don't know what your variable's type is. Text files are strings, so an `FString` can be directly saved to a text file. Anything else you will need to convert.

A number can be converted to a string in many ways (a string of the digits, an octet, or something like Base64). For this example I will assume a number would be saved as the text representation of its digits (i.e. an `int32` of value `100` number would become an `FString` with the value `"100"`).

```
// .cpp
void SomeClass::SomeFunction() {
    FString YourString;

    // if saving a string, just make a string
    YourString = TEXT("This is some text");

    // if saving an integer, convert it to string
    int32 YourInteger = 100;
    ourString = FString::FromInt( YourInteger );
    
    // or if it's a float, convert it as well
    float YourFloat = 3.14f;
    YourString = FString::SanitizeFloat( YourFloat );

    // then, save it to file
    FString Filename = TEXT("some kind of file path here");
    FFileHelper::SaveStringToFile(YourString, *Filename);
}
```